# Como traduzir as mensagens de ajuda do Click

Tags: python

Não consegui traduzir suas mensagens para o português da biblioteca [**Click**](https://pypi.org/project/click/):

exemplo.py

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--name')
def hello(name):
    """Exibe uma saudação."""
    click.echo(f'Olá {name}!')

hello()
```

Chamando `python exemplo.py --help`, obtém-se:

```
Usage: z.py [OPTIONS]

  Exibe uma saudação.

Options:
  --name TEXT
  --help       Show this message and exit.
```

Quero que apareça `Modo de uso` ao invés de `usage` e `Mostra esta mensagem e sai` ao invés de `Show this message and exit`.

Comment: Olhei na documentação e comparando com o que passou faltou argumentos e esqueceu  de incluir a configurações. acho que é dessa forma que a documentação informa :  `@click.command(help='Exibe uma saudação.', help_option_names=['-h', '--help'], context_settings=dict(help_option_names=['-h', '--help'], metavar='[opções]'))
@click.option('--name')`

Comment: Sempre que alguém me responde com referência à documentação, bate-me um certo constrangimento, pois acho que poderia ter buscado um pouco mais.
A verdade é que, tendo deficiência visual, nem sempre a navegação das páginas favorece o melhor desempenho dos leitores de telas e, assim, por vezes, não encontro.
De qualquer modo, é sempre muito bom encontrar cá pessoas gentis como você, que partilham do que sabe, pelo simples gosto de fazer a vida do outro um pouco mais fácil.
Muito, muito obrigado!